# Unable to run docker image amazonlinux:2017.03 on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, docker, yum

This is what I see on my console when I run `docker run -t amazonlinux:2017.03`:

```
> docker run -t amazonlinux:2017.03  
Unable to find image 'amazonlinux:2017.03' locally
2017.03: Pulling from library/amazonlinux
0793c64286b7: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:7c781c9234e712f135ee402a13ffd5dbf342a9ff1394c73bc5ae4d9b9078e0f8
Status: Downloaded newer image for amazonlinux:2017.03
bash-4.2# 

yum
```

I press `ENTER` a few times and then type `yum`. The system is not responding.

Why it is the case? Is there any solution.

My goal is to use `aws-log` in a docker container eventually. That's why I want to try out an aws docker image

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
docker run -it amazonlinux:2017.03
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground): 
"For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process."